# Appending to a Realm List Only if Unique Primary Key

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am implementing Realm in my iOS project and wondering if there is a way to append an `Object` to a `List` only if the `Object`'s primary key is unique. Currently I have something like:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let message = RealmMessage()
message.id = 99999
message.desc = "Please Help!"
let chatroom = realm.objects(RealmChatRoom.self)[0]
try! realm.write {
    chatroom.messages.append(message)
}
```

However this will crash if the messages is already in the list.

I know that complete objects can be updated using something like:

```
try! realm.write {
        realm.add(chatRoom, update: .modified)
    }
```

But does something like this exist for `append`? I.e. only write if unique key otherwise overwrite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a list of objects in Realm DB Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546847/how-to-update-a-list-of-objects-in-realm-db-swift)

Comment: Primary keys must be unique. *Declaring a primary key allows objects to be looked up and updated efficiently and enforces uniqueness for each value*. The way you are setting up your primary key is the issue - one solution is to use `NSUUID().UUIDString` to assign the key. They will guarantee uniqueness and alleviate the issue. You would know if the message is already in the list as you would have loaded it to make that change, and can then update it via it's primary key. See [Updating Objects with Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

Answer (score 0):

List stores the object references and its elements auto-update with `message` update. So if `chatroom.messages` contains a `message`, no need to append it again. As a result you can use this code for updating:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(message, update: .modified)
    if !chatroom.messages.contains(message) {
        chatroom.messages.append(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don’t need to add the message first in the code above just appending is enough and it will auto-add it. It’s not what I’m looking for though I want to append without first checking if the messages contain the message.